# Selenium-Webdriver Explicit Wait Apache JMeter 5.5

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Selenium Webdriver in Apache Jmeter 5.5 and require to use explicit wait.The Script Language is Java.
Here, is my Sample Code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

var driver=WDS.browser;

// Load Url
driver.get("https://samplewebsite.com");
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1936, 1048));
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='content']")).click();

// Login 
WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("sampleUsername");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("samplePassword");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span")).click();
// login details
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

In the above code I was facing the below no such element exception:

> Target exception: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//input[@type='email']"}

*Blockquote*

So, I used explicit wait as recommended, But, I am facing the following error:

```
 Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import or . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: ofSeconds() on undefined variable or class name: Duration : at Line: 15 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import or . . . '' : Duration .ofSeconds ( 10 ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import or . . . '' at line number 15
```

All the xpaths are verified and correct, I am unable find a resolution to above error.
I am facing this source file evaluation error for any troubleshooting I am doing.

> My objective is to an correct explicit wait before we enter the username & password details in email & password fields respectively.

```
// Login 
WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("sampleUsername");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("samplePassword");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to (at least) import the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class:

```
import java.time.Duration
```

Also don't be confused with `java` because if you think it's "java" - it is not, you're actually using [Beanshell interpreter](https://beanshell.github.io/) which is not 100% Java-compatible.

If you want to use something closer to Java - consider switching to [`groovy` language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), moreover it's the [recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)